# Using CakePDF Image not showing

Tags: cakephp, pdf-generation, cakephp-2.3

I am using CakePHP 2.3.6. I setup everything alright, bootstrap & core files are ok.

Now, the pdf file is generating nicely, but it doesn't have any image. But, my view file has an image, because I want that image in my generated pdf file.

I tried using `fullbase=>true`, but still my image is not showing in the pdf file

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Please post a sample of your code to show how you generated the .pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got a solution to this. Search for the following line

```
def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE",false);
```

Make the line like bellow

```
def("DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE",true);
```

Comment: in which file is this located in?